# How to perform a SELECT with more than one field in Firebase Database in Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

First of all, i've searched in many places but i didn't find the answer to this question at all, so, i am asking it here. But, i would like to know: How can i convert a query like this: *** SELECT a, b, c FROM MyTable *** in Firebase Database in Android ? The approach i tried follows below:

```
public void testQueryMethod(final PhisicianHandler handler) {

    final String databaseReference = "CadastroMedico";

    database.getReference(databaseReference)
            .child("mDoctorID")
            .child("mNome")
            .child("mEspecialidade")
            .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {

                    ArrayList<String> dadosMedico = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        dadosMedico.add(snapshot.getValue().toString());
                        System.out.println(snapshot.getValue().toString());
                    }
                    handler.trataMedico(dadosMedico);
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
}
```

My whole Model

public class FirebaseDatabaseModel {

```
//Creating the instance of the database
private FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

public ArrayList<String> dataRetriever(final ArrayList<String> dadosMedicosRecebidos, final BaseAdapter adapter) {

    final String tableName = "Especialidade";
    final String childToBeOrdered = "NomesEspecialidades";

    database.getReference(tableName).orderByChild(childToBeOrdered)
            .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {

                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        dadosMedicosRecebidos.add(snapshot.getValue().toString());
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });

    return dadosMedicosRecebidos;
}

/**
 * This method gets all the registries where specialty is equal to the selected item on the spinner
 */
public void queryMethod(String selectedItem, final PhisicianHandler handler) {

    final String tableName = "CadastroMedico";
    final String childToBeOrdered = "mEspecialidade";

    database.getReference(tableName)
            .orderByChild(childToBeOrdered)
            .equalTo(selectedItem)
            .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {

                    ArrayList<String> dadosMedico = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        dadosMedico.add(snapshot.getValue().toString());
                    }
                    handler.trataMedico(dadosMedico);
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
}

public void userIdQueryMethod(final PhisicianHandler handler) {

    final String tableName = "UserID";
    final String childToBeOrdered = "ID/UserID";

    database.getReference(tableName).orderByChild(childToBeOrdered)
            .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {

                    ArrayList<String> dadosMedico = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        dadosMedico.add(snapshot.getValue().toString());
                    }
                    handler.trataMedico(dadosMedico);
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
}

public void doctorIdQueryMethod(final PhisicianHandler handler) {

    final String tableName = "DoctorID";
    final String childToBeOrdered = "ID/DoctorID";

    database.getReference(tableName).orderByChild(childToBeOrdered)
            .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {

                    ArrayList<String> dadosMedico = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        dadosMedico.add(snapshot.getValue().toString());
                    }
                    handler.trataMedico(dadosMedico);
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
}

public void testQueryMethod(String specialty, final PhisicianHandler handler) {

    final String tableName = "CadastroMedico";
    final String childToBeOrdered = "mEspecialidade";

    DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("CadastroMedico");

            database.child("mDoctorID")
            .child("mNome")
            .child("mEspecialidade")
            .orderByChild(childToBeOrdered)
            .equalTo(specialty);

            database.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {

                    ArrayList<String> dadosMedico = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : 
            dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

            dadosMedico.add(snapshot.getValue().toString());                           
            System.out.println(snapshot.getValue().toString());

                }
                    handler.trataMedico(dadosMedico);
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, 
                String prevChildKey) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, 
                    String prevChildKey) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
}
```

}

But it didn't work for me. I got this message when i try to show it on the Log window: I/System.out: propertyValue:false and i don't get any value from my base. I will add an image so that you can see what i am talking about.

[Image 1: The fields i'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGD34.png)

[Document: Screenshots of my whole database](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxcmLP3Jo8wnb2xBMm5SM3JJeWc)

What i would like to do is (In SQL just for example): *** SELECT mDoctorID, mEmail, mEndereço FROM CadastroMedico; ***

I think it is possible to do, but i don't know how to do it yet. I would appreciate some thoughts about it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("CadastroMedico");
        mDatabase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {

                String doctorID=dataSnapshot.child("mDoctorId").getValue(String.class);
                String mNome=dataSnapshot.child("mNome").getValue(String.class);
                handler.trataMedico(dadosMedico);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
```

Comment: It removed the warnings on my code, but i still don't get any value from my Firebase database

Comment: That is because the reference is wrong, post your whole structure of the database

Comment: Screenshot of your whole database, but with the nodes that are on top of what you provided

Comment: Ok i will do it

Comment: @Caio i dont mean the fields, what you are doing wrong is the getReference code, and for doing that right i need to see the whole database, take a pic of all of its parents

Comment: I don't know if it was what you asked me, but i posted my whole Database class and all my database screenshots are on the second link. If you need something else, please let me know

Comment: @Caio i edited my answer, this is going to work, try it

Comment: It is bringing me all the data inside "CadastroMedico", but i would like to get just 3 fields based on a where clause. I modified my code so that you can see what i want to accomplish. But it is getting the data.

Comment: Just get separate strings, check my answer

Comment: I see. But i am already doing this in my code, i get the data and after i separate it, but i would like to get just a few fields and avoid to bring all this data because, for example, inside the node  "CadastroUsuario", there is the value "password". What i wouldn't like to do is to get the password for example, to get the user's name that comes with it, because it doesn't make sense. I shouldn't have to bring all this data just to use one or two values. That's my point. And of course, save the user's data not bringing all this data. Just the necessary. I don't know if you understood me.

Comment: Because both User's name and password are in the same node

Answer (score 0):

- Create a class and declare all variables you want to fetch from firebase in it. In your case, they will be mDoctorID,mNome, and mEspecialidade.
- Add `@IgnoreExtraProperties` before class keyword
- Make sure the name of the variable is exactly same as the name of the node in Firebase.It will look like this:

  ```
  @IgnoreExtraProperties
  class CadastroMedico{
      public String mDoctorID="", mNome="", mEspecialidade="";
  }
  ```
- Now call firebase database query, if you want to fetch data only once use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`. Assuming that you want data only once, as SELECT query also returns data only once, the code will look something like this:

  ```
  reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(){
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          List<CadastroMedico> dadosMedico = new ArrayList();
          for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
              CadastroMedico cadastroMedico = snapshot.getValue(CadastroMedico.class)
              dadosMedico.add(cadastroMedico);
              System.out.println(cadastroMedico.mDoctorID + " " + cadastroMedico.mNome + " " +cadastroMedico.mEspecialidade);
          }
          //modify your handler accordingly
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
          //handle error
      }});
  ```

Comment: Ok Kamran, i will try it. Thanks